# Google Speech-To-Text skips parts of audio randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

I have Dutch phone calls, and I'm using Google STT (long_running_recognize) to transcribe them. Everything works correctly, but many words aren't recognized. The transcription seems to stop randomly for a few seconds every now and then. The not-recognized parts are represented as very long timestamps. For example, there's one word that takes ~0.5 seconds from around 17s in reality, but has a timestamp of 11.5s - 17.5s, so ~5.5 seconds of well-intelligible speech are not recognized.

This is the configuration I use:

```
CONFIG = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding = speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16, # optional for WAV
    # model="phone_call", # this doesn't exist for Dutch
    sample_rate_hertz = 8000, # default value
    language_code="nl-NL", # language code
    enable_word_time_offsets=True # return hit timestamps
)
```

This is the information (using `mediainfo`) of one recording.

```
General
Complete name                            : 20161130_215643_31651118731.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 2.30 MiB
Duration                                 : 2mn 30s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf57.25.100

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 2mn 30s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 8 000 Hz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 2.30 MiB (100%)
```

I can't share audio or transcription because of privacy reasons, but the recognized words are mostly correct and the timestamps are also right.

Why is this? Are the parts that were not transcribed unintelligable by Google, especially given this language model? Can I do something to increase the number of recognized words?

Comment: Have you already tried the phone_call enhanced model which is really intended for transcribing audio where the source is phone calls https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/phone-model ... Also, since the source is phone call, it may be because that the audio is not of good quality (with lots of background noise, etc) which may cause poor recognition by the service.

Comment: "Note: The Speech-to-Text API supports the phone_call model for the en-US language only. For other languages, use the video or default models." So yes, I tried, but that just gives me warnings and errors.

Comment: Aha, yes. I totally forgot it's only available for US English only. You may want to file a feature request to support Dutch in the future or check the best practices and make sure that the audio file does not have much background noise. https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in control of the sound quality (and this link advices to not mess with the original signal). I would prefer Google to return wrong words instead of skipping words it's uncertain about, but I guess I'll have to deal with it. Thanks anyway.